# factory girl pass argument to many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :house do
    after(:create) do |house, evaluator|
      evaluator.members.each do |member|
        create(:house_member, house: house, member: member, position: 2)
      end 
    end
  end

FactoryGirl.create_list(:house, 4, members: FactoryGirl.create_list(:member, 3))
```

How can I pass the argument position in the `FactoryGirl.create_list`? This is a many to many relation.

table house:

```
:id, :name
```

table member:

```
:id, :name
```

table house_member:

```
:id, :house_id, :member_id, :position
```

Comment: Can you include the models? Is position an attribute of house_member?

Comment: yes, sure! updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `transient attributes` like.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  transient do
    position 2
    members []
  end

  factory :house do
    after(:create) do |house, evaluator|
      evaluator.members.each do |member|
        create(:house_member, house: house, member: member, position: evaluator.position)
      end 
    end
  end
```

Now you can pass the argument `position` in the `FactoryGirl.create_list` like this,

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(:house, 4, position: 44, members: FactoryGirl.create_list(:member, 3))
```

Comment: yes, but this will create position 44 for all. I want to specify the position for each house_member

Comment: your right. If you want to create different objects, then  `create_list` could not help you. There is no way to use create_list with different values for the same attribute

Use `create` and do it individual.

Comment: you can use `FactoryGirl.create_list(:house, 4, positions: [1,2,3], members: FactoryGirl.create_list(:member, 3))` and do `evaluator.members.each_with_index |member, i| ` and do `position: evaluator.positions[i]`. This one could be one solution. `positions   array length and `members` list legth should be same.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly you can't pass attributes when creating join records implicitly in Rails.

Given:

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :house_members
  has_many :members, through: house_members
end

class HouseMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :house
  belongs_to :member
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :house_members
  has_many :houses, through: :house_members
end
```

When I do:

```
house = House.create(name: 'Fallingwater')
house.members.create(name: 'Max')
```

Its not possible to pass attributes for the HouseMember model which acts a join.
Instead you need to explicitly create the join model:

```
house = House.create
house.house_members.create(member: Member.create(name: 'Max'), position: 2)
```

Or alter the record after the fact:

```
house = House.create(name: 'Fallingwater')
member = house.members.create(name: 'Max')
house.house_members
     .where(member: member).first.update_attribute(position: 2)
```

How does this apply to you?

When you do:

```
evaluator.members.each do |member|
  create(:house_member, house: house, member: member, position: 2)
end
```

You're actually creating duplicate join models. If you had been a good boy/girl and added a unique compound index on `house_id` and `member_id` you would get an error.

What you can do is alter the the join record:

```
evaluator.house_members.each do |hm|
  hm.update_attribute(position: 2)
end
```

Depending on what position actually is in your application you might want to handle it by setting a default value in the DB instead though.

Answer (score 0):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :class do
  trait :with_comments do
   transient do
     email {nil}
     address {nil}
     id {nil}
   end

   after(:create) do |class, evaluator|
     class.students << FactoryGirl.create(:students, :id => evaluator.id, :email => evaluator.email, :address => evaluator.address )
   end
 end
end
```

Pass arguments to factory :class as

```
@class = create(:class, :with_comments, id: 1, email: 'abc@gmail.com', address: 'House No. XYZ')
```